# Is it possible to change the WYSIWYG in CS-Cart?

Tags: wysiwyg, cs-cart

I would need to change the default editor use in CS-Cart, or at least try to add some more user-friendly buttonas (such as images uploads, and so on...)

Is there a way to change or modify the standard WYSIWYG  editor in CS-Cart?

Answer (score 2):

CS-cart has by default 3 wysiwyg editors, TinyMCE, CKEditor and Redactor and can be selected from backend, Settings > Appearance

Comment: Also in v3 is present but are only 2 editors available, TinyMCE & CKEditor, but you can use TinyMCE and edit config file js/editors/tinymce.editor.js (here http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php you can find available options)